# pass python objects in ROS messages and services

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to define a ROS message or service with arbitrary python objects? Is the only option to use a string and use json.dumps / json.loads?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280344/pass-python-objects-in-ros-messages-and-services/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2018-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way to define a ROS message or service with arbitrary python objects?

Assuming you mean: can I have fields with types of 'arbitrary Python types', then: no.

> Is the only option to use a string and use json.dumps / json.loads?

Don't know whether it's the *only* way, but it is *a* way.

Can you clarify why you'd want to do this?

It's a really heavy and invasive form of coupling, which limits reusability of your components.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on 2018-01-20**:
I use a python ORM to read/write to a database, and I was considering having a ROS node with services for each database operation. I could a) send the python object to the service to save, b) send just the properties and have the service create a new object, or c) use the ORM directly. not sure.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-21**:
In any case: ROS 1 msg IDL only supports primitive types or composites of those types. See [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification).